# Upload a file with App Inventor 2 to a server through PHP

Tags: php, post, file-upload, app-inventor

I am trying to upload a file with App Inventor 2 to a server through PHP. I followed the [Photo Booth Android app](https://amerkashi.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/how-to-develop-a-photo-boot-android-app/) tutorial, however server-side, myPhoto.jpg contains the filename, not the picture's content (e.g. myPhoto.jpg contains something like "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/app_inventor_1424997354199.jpg"). How can I fix it?

The code I use:

[image]

tempSaveFile.php :

```
<?php
 
$dataToWrite = $_REQUEST['fileName'];
$fileName = "myPhoto.jpg";     
file_put_contents($fileName, $dataToWrite);
 
?>
```

I am aware of [Taifun's tutorial](https://puravidaapps.com/postfile.php) but since in my php.ini `always_populate_raw_post_data = On` I would prefer to avoid having to install anything.

[Scott's tutorial](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/app-inventor-developers-library/Sc4a1wZHL-Q/OxTndqsHUxQJ) seems to do something similar (with App Inventor 1):

[image]

[image]

Comment: The simple solution is to set the flag `always_populate_raw_post_data = On` and then follow Scott's example. If you are not able set that flag, you will have to follow that [workaround](https://puravidaapps.com/postfile.php) you can find on my webpage...

Comment: also use *Do it* to debug your blocks, for example how does `txtPictureToPost.Text` look like? you might want to replace your screenshot by a screenshot including *Do it* result...

Comment: remember: the `PostFile` block expects the complete path to your file, e.g. *file:///mnt/sdcard/myImage.jpg*

Comment: @Taifun Thanks, I have in my php.ini `always_populate_raw_post_data = On` but still have the issue :/

Comment: @Taifun `txtPictureToPost.Text` contains something like "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/app_inventor_1424997354199.jpg", i.e. full path to the pic.

Comment: @Taifun But instead of transferring the picture, post only transfers the full path to the pic :/

Comment: in the URL you should only transfer the filename without path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the URL you should only transfer the filename without path, e.g. `app_inventor_1424997354199.jpg`

in the `PostFile` block you should use the complete path, e.g. `file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/app_inventor_1424997354199.jpg`

[image]

then on the server, try Scott's solution

```
<?PHP
   $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
   if (!(file_put_contents($_GET['fileName'],$data) === FALSE)) echo "File xfer completed."; // file could be empty, though
   else echo "File xfer failed.";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Also in postfile.php in your tuto, which is more complete (I like the error handling), I replaced`$data = php_compat_file_get_contents('php://stdin');` by `$data = file_get_contents('php://input');`, it made it work (without having to use the PEAR package)