# How to Upload Video to Rails Server from App Inventor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, app-inventor

My goal is essentially to upload a video file, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28767974/8936119), but with Ruby on Rails instead of PHP.  I can successfully send JSON data to my server, but haven't been able to get file uploads working.  The end objective is to have the file be in the server's `/tmp` directory, just like files uploaded via a webpage `file_field_tag`.

This image:
[image: code blocks]
shows what I've tried so far. The result is that on the server, the parameter list is empty, unlike if you had used a `file_field_tag`.  In the PHP example, they are able to get the contents of the file from the input stream... maybe there is something similar in Rails?

I know my API works, as I was able to successfully make a request using a JavaScript `XMLHttpRequest`, so I'm led to believe the solution involves working around what App Inventor offers for HTTP requests.

Edit: Removed unsupported header since the PHP example doesn't use headers anyways

Comment: please include your code

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio please see the provided [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVstc.png) for my blocks, let me know if you need any other code ...

Comment: multipart/form-data is not supported in the web component of App Inventor. [How to use the PostFile block in App Inventor](http://puravidaapps.com/postfile.php)